# How to implement value incrementation for a specific key using Redis in Nest.js?

Tags: caching, redis, nestjs

I'm working on a Nest.js application where I need to implement a feature to increment a value associated with a particular key using Redis. However, I couldn't find a straightforward way to achieve this using the redis module in Nest.js.

I've already installed the Redis module in my project and established a connection to the Redis server. However, I'm unsure about how to use the incr command to increment the value for a specific key within my Nest.js application.

Could someone provide guidance on how to correctly implement value incrementation for a particular key using Redis in a Nest.js application? Any insights, code snippets, or examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { CacheModule } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { redisStore } from 'cache-manager-redis-yet';
import { RedisService } from './redis.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register({
      useFactory: () => ({
        store: redisStore,
        host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
        password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [RedisService],
  exports: [RedisService],
})
export class RedisModule {}
```

```
import { CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';

@Injectable()
export class RedisUtilityService {
  constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private readonly cache: Cache) {}

    async incrementCache(key: string) {
        const client = await this.cache.store.getClient();
        const value = await client.incr(key);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Getting error -> Property 'getClient' does not exist on type 'Store'.